# Must have libdb to build apt-ftparchive

Tags: apt, makefile

I'm trying to build APT.  However, I keep getting this message from the ftparchive makefile:

```
Must have libdb to build apt-ftparchive
```

It doesn't always print this, only sometimes?  Which package do I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

**libdb**: The Berkeley Database (Berkeley DB) is a programmatic toolkit that provides embedded database support for both traditional and client/server applications. Berkeley DB is used by many applications, including Python and Perl, so this should be **installed on all systems**.

you can install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1
```

But I assume it must be already installed, if so then I think your problem looks like the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1274466) stated here.

Comment: Sure? not `libdb5.1-dev`?